# padding or margin coming from somewhere?

Tags: css, margin, padding

I have checked and rechecked the padding and margins on all the elements for this page but there is a break between the #header and #container on this page. There should be no band of white.  I tried giving the #container a neg. margin too, but that just ends up cutting off and disappearing. Any idea what I am doing wrong and where it is coming from?  Thanks so much! http://circore.com/ais/[image]

Comment: A space could cause that.  Get rid of any spaces after your image in your header.

Comment: you have some padding, margin, height and negativ margin. Even spans wrapping Divs. Clean up your code, and try to reset your css more efficiently. It's a bit messy, it won't help to keep it straight and cross browser., cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran firebug and did this:

`#guy > img { position: absolute; }`

and

`#secondary { padding-bottom: 0; }`

which got rid of it in firefox.

I am not saying this is the correct fix for your current situation, but it may lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

1) remove line-height: 18px; css of the body element
2) remove padding-bottom: 20px; from #secondary element
the result will be this[image]

is this the result you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `float: left;` from `#guy` and the `padding` from `#secondary`, and you're good.

Also, as a side note, [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) doesn't apply to elements that are not `position: absolute` or `position: relative` (and some other edge cases like `opacity` < 1).

```
#guy {
    /* float: left; */ 
    margin: -178px 0px 20px 305px;
    /* z-index: 2000; */
}

#secondary {
    background: url(images/bottomswoop.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 940px;
    clear: both;
    /* padding-bottom: 20px; */
    height: 200px;
}
```